# \pause not working properly, going backwards

Tags: beamer, align, pause

So I would like to use \pause in its normal way, but it is revealing stuff backwards and I don't know why!!!!

```
\documentclass[usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, commath, array, tcolorbox, cancel, caption, subcaption, graphicx, multicol,beamerthemesplit,stmaryrd,comment, color,movie15,animate}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Madrid}


\begin{document}
    %6 slide
\begin{frame}{Introducción: La función gamma}
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1} dt \\\pause
\text{Integrando por partes, obtenemos:}\\ 
\Gamma(x+1) &= \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x}dt\\ \pause
&= \lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x}dt\\ \pause
&=\lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \Big[-e^{-t}t^x \Big|_0^B + x \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt \Big] \\ \pause
&= x \lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt\\ \pause
&= x\Gamma(x) 
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also, I'm new here, I am so sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Off-topic, but you don't need `graphicx` or `color` with beamer, as beamer already provides this functionality.

Comment: And package `movie15` is obsolete and superseded by `media9`

Comment: `\pause` basically doesn't work in `align` and `align*` environment.  Pretty sure I've seen it documented somewhere.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch would it work if it did nothing on the measuring pass, do you know?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch seems to:-)  I'll answer...

Comment: Section 23.4 in the manual of beamer

Answer (score 3):

`align` gets executed twice and you need to make `\pause` keep out of the way of the first run:

```
\documentclass[usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, commath, array, tcolorbox, cancel, caption, subcaption, graphicx, multicol,beamerthemesplit,stmaryrd,comment, color,movie15,animate}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\makeatletter
\def\zzpause{\ifmeasuring@\else\expandafter\pause\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    %6 slide
\begin{frame}{Introducción: La función gamma}
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1} dt \\\zzpause
\text{Integrando por partes, obtenemos:}\\ 
\Gamma(x+1) &= \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x}dt\\ \zzpause
&= \lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x}dt\\ \zzpause
&=\lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \Big[-e^{-t}t^x \Big|_0^B + x \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt \Big] \\ \zzpause
&= x \lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt\\ \zzpause
&= x\Gamma(x) 
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround:

```
\documentclass[usenames, dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, mathtools, commath, array, tcolorbox, cancel, caption, subcaption, stmaryrd,comment, media9,animate}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\useoutertheme{split}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

%6 slide
\begin{frame}{Introducción: La función gamma}
\begin{align*}
\visible<+->{\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1} dt} \\
\visible<+->{\text{Integrando por partes, obtenemos:}}\\ 
\visible<.->{\Gamma(x+1) &= \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x}dt}\\ 
\visible<+->{&= \lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x}dt}\\ 
\visible<+->{&=\lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \Big[-e^{-t}t^x \Big|_0^B + x \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt \Big]} \\ 
\visible<+->{&= x \lim_{B \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^B e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt}\\ 
\visible<+->{&= x\Gamma(x)} 
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```